# Where is the ringing telephone in Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In *Batman: Arkham City* I've overheard several prisoners in the Bowery talking about a ringing telephone, saying that whoever answers it will die. Where can I find the phone in question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a side-mission: there are several payphones throughout Arkham City, which have a random chance of ringing when you get close. They will be called out on your HUD. If you reach one in time (you can't be in combat, though it'll wait for you) you'll be able to advance the mission. If you miss a ringing phone, you won't be penalised; however, during the mission, you may have to pick up a phone before a timer expires, and missing this phone *will* penalise you.

As a hint, there's one Batman villain whose modus operandi involves making an innocent choice that leads to your inevitable demise/release. He also appeared in Arkham Asylum.

Comment: I've actually finished all the sidequests since I posted this, I forgot to mark a solution as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I found one in Park Row, northeast of the court house, under the overpass. Didn't realize it also gave me the [Ring Ring achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a155654/ring-ring-achievement.htm). From what I see, there are quite a few ringing phones to find.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later in the game Zsas will call you on one of these phones. When you hear it ringing, use detective mode to see it ringing . Kinda of like a bat's sonar.